# rule about using present perfect with present simple

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

I can't find on internet the rule.

To you native speakers, if the second part of the sentence uses present simple, does it involve using the present perfect tense in the first part because of the consequences in the present?

In the sentences:
"They have for sure seen my message for the payment because I can see that my account is no longer blocked"

"The country has been colonized, this is why we can see similitaries today" but it could imply that the country is still colonized(present perfect) whereas the colonization was past.

To me, in both sentence, they do not need present perfect but I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's correct.

Present perfect is a *present* tense. The topic is something that happened in the past or began in the past, but it is always indirectly talking about the present.

Your first sentence, "*They have for sure seen my message for the payment...*, means, "They know I have made the payment".

The second sentence means, "The country has a history of being colonized."

Comment: When you talk about "past or began in the past"; if I use my sentence "the country has been colonized" it means it's past but if I add an since/ for, it's began in the past?  By "they know I have made the payment" you mean "they know i have already made..."?

Comment: @safarie This is starting to go off-topic from your question, which didn't ask about "for" and "since", which have special rules that you can find in many other questions on this site. In this context, I don't see any difference between "...have made..." and "...have *already* made..."

Comment: _The country has been colonised in the past_ sounds fine to me and doesn't imply that it is still a colony.

Comment: @KateBunting By itself it's natural, but with "*this is why we can see similarities **today***", it's unnatural to compare present to present.

Comment: We don't know what 'similarities' are being referred to - what two things are being compared -  but the fact that the country has a colonial past has an effect on its situation today.

Comment: @KateBunting It's distracting from the OP's question, so I've just removed it